# Facebook openGraph api limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get a list of users who go to an event the following query:

```
EVENT_ID / attending
```

But it returns only a portion of users (4000 of 22000). In what may be the problem?

**#UPD**
This is a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293819407299977)

How to get the number of members?